# Is there a way to sync saves across multiple devices

Tags: ios, star-wars-tiny-death-star

I wanna be able to play tiny Death Star on my ipad and my iphone, not at the same time but depending on when I'm at home or not...

I don't see an obvious way to do this, although since it's a Game Center game, it seems like it should support it?

Comment: So you're trying to sync progress between multiple devices?

Comment: Yes, basically I'm hoping to be able to shift from my ipad at home to my iphone when at work.

Answer (score 2):

The new Facebook integration is supposed to make this possible.

Signing into Facebook in the app and then signing in on your other device should make the games sync.

I haven't personally installed the app on my phone (in addition to my iPad) to see if it works.

Edit: Apparently, in the iOS version, this is not currently functional but is a known bug. Hopefully they will update to fix it soon.

Answer (score -2):

No, this isnt possible as it doesnt save via any sort of cloud.

Read below in comments, facebook integration is pending, but is not working. This is a known bug, posted on the developers website.

Comment: On Android if you sign in with Facebook you can play across devices. Is this not also possible on iOS?

Comment: The facebook integration is not working. its a known bug. Go look at the developers website to see this.

Comment: That's too bad that it's broken.  I did notice that the FB integration on the iPad isn't working so I guess that's something for them to fix.

Comment: While it may not be working now, that doesn't mean that they don't attempt cloud saving, it just means that right now said cloud saving is possibly working incorrectly.

Comment: @General Windu: that's an odd statement since occasionally the game "gets out-of-sync" between the local device and the servers... this indicates for sure that its cloud based.